# How to load one or more JS/CSS files if one source is blocked?

Tags: javascript, google-cdn

Here is my situation

I am creating some website that loads JavaScript from CDN like Google/jscdn.com. But some of them were totally blocked in China. But 50% of my visitors are from China and the other are from other countries. Is it possible to load one more source if the particular one is blocked?

For example, if `googleapis.com` is blocked, I will load from `lib.sinaapp.com` which is accessible from China. And I want to load them in given order: try `googleapis.com` first then `lib.sinaapp.com`.

Is it possible to do this without server-side code?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason to not load them all from the one that's allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cdn fallback technique.

Example:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

There's a nice article about [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

Comment: This is a very good way. But the problem is that the CN government blocks the Google CDN host and somehow the request is in pending. So it'd take a very long time to execute the `$ || xxx` code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to know if the request is going to succeed or fail until it is complete. Perhaps you want a solution that checks Google, then times out and switches to another URL if there's no response after xx seconds?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using a JavaScript file loader like **[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)** or **[YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/)**.

They allow you to load JavaScript files dynamically and you can control when a file should be loaded.

Here is a simple implementation of your requirement with YepNope:

```
//assuming that your JavaScript file is script.js
//put this flag in both script.js files
var scriptLoaded = true;

//put this in your main JS file
yepnope([{
  load: 'http://googleapis.com/123/script.js', //load this one first
  complete: function () {
    if (!scriptLoaded) {
      yepnope('http://lib.sinaapp.com/123/script.js');  //if not already loaded, load this file
    }
  }
}]);
```